# Can someone explain the handleChage function which changes states of the inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

const [data , setData] = ({firstname:'' , lastname:'' , password:''});

const handleChange = (e) => {
setData({...data , [e.target.name] : e.target.value })

I am new to react and java script and can't figure out why ...data(for destructuring) is used is handlechange() function and what is the use of [] braces in [e.target.name] : e.target.value

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `...data` (destructuring) is being used so that other attributes already present in `data` are not affected by the change to the attribute that triggered the event that is actually calling `handleChange()`.
For example, suppose you have a form that has the fields: "Name", "Age", and "Profession". Suppose you fill the form fields in the same above order. As you fill each form field and `handleChange()` is called your `data` object gets updated:

When filling the name:
`{ name: "John" }`

When filling age:
`{ name: "John", age: "20" }`

When filling profession:
`{ name: "John", age: "20", profession: "student" }`

`...data` (destructuring) is a way to ensure the previous attributes are preserved as you add or update new attributes to the `data` object.

For the second part of your question, the square brackets are used to ensure javascript will evaluate `e.target.name` and use its value as the attribute to be added or updated to `data`. The form input fields for this example, should have the `name` attributes as "name", "age", and "profession", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "long" version of the handleChange function. I think it will help you understand the function mission easier.

```
cons handleChange = (e) => {
  const currentData = data;
  currentData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  setData(currentData)
}
```

The first is the three dots with an object like `...data`. It's almost the same with `Object.assign`. In this case, it help you create a new object from the value of data.

```
const data = {firstname:'' , lastname:'' , password:''};
const newData = {...data}; // {firstname:'' , lastname:'' , password:''}
```

The second is the [] braces. If you want to set a property key from a variable inside the {}. You may use the [] braces to wrap this variable.

```
const key = 'name';
const a = {[key]: 'John'} // {name: 'John'}.
```

This is not really related to React, you may get the function like this in other places. Some articles you may read about them:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax